# How in Jenkins to do an action before aborted

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How to call some kind of script in jenkins before interruption? For example, I have a long operation, and I want to take a screenshot before the process stops by timeout. I want to see where the process stopped

```
stage("Start")
    {
        options{
            timeout(time: 1, unit: 'MINUTES')
        }
        steps   {
                // Start long command
                //Screenshot 1.jpg
                }  
    }
    post {
        always {
            archiveArtifacts '1.jpg'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Descriptive pipelines, as in your example, moving the 'screenshot' to the `post` should do the trick

```
 stage("Start"){
   options{
     timeout(time: 1, unit: 'MINUTES')
   }
   steps {
     // Start long command
   }  
}
post {
  always {
    // take Screenshot
    archiveArtifacts '1.jpg'
  }
}
```

If you decide to try Scripted pipelines (or [include a Script block](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script) on your current one), you could do something like

```
try {
  timeout(20) {
    // Start long command
  }
} finally {
  // take Screenshot
}
```

Since you are mentioning 'screenshot' in a pipeline that by nature is headless, I'm wondering what are you referring to.

If you want to capture a screenshot of an integration test in WebDriver, Selenium or similar, it should be the testing script the one that has the timeout and that takes the screenshot on failure.

Please, explain a bit more your scenario in order to provide a better answer.

Comment: In this case, the screenshot will be after closing the script window

Comment: The script starts the program with a head that sometimes freezes with an error. By timeout, jenkins abort them. I want to know a mistake

Comment: You could run two steps in parallel, sharing the same head. One with the long-running script, and another with a timer and the screen capture command.
To be able to stop the second stage when the first one finishes with success, I would use an Env variable `env.SCRIPT_SUCCESS`, set it to `false` by default, and change it to `true` on script success. Then, on the second stage, create a loop that checks on the env variable every X seconds, and if not true after Y iterations, take the screenshot and then fail the stage. https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel

Comment: @АндрейФокин, would you mind editing the answer with the snippet of what actually worked for you, so the right answers is recored here. Thank you,